matrix calculus derivative of M * M^T
I'm a freshman studying matrix differentiation, and I'm hoping someone could kindly explain the following to me.
Could you please tell me why $\frac{dMM^T}{dM}=2M^T$, where $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix?
I'm a bit confused, as I would have expected the result to be a matrix of size $n \times n \times n \times n$, rather than just $n \times n$.
Detail of the claim

According to wikipedia, there is not a common definition of matrix by matrix differentiation…

Yeah, @Zhenya could you please provide which reference makes that claim, because it’s not clear from here what definition is being adopted for matrix derivatives?

Thank you for your time @DiracComb16796. It's about the gradient computation in the Gaussian Splatting algorithm, I have put the related part into the link.

Right, the solution should be for $\frac{d tr(MM^{\top})}{dM}$

$
\def\d{\delta}
\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mb#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\blue#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\blue{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\green{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Your expectation is absolutely correct and the claim is bogus.
First, recall that the component-wise self-gradients of a matrix are
$$\eqalign{
\grad{M}{M_{kl}} \;=\; e_k\,e_l^T, \q\q\q
\grad{M^T}{M_{kl}} \;=\; e_l\,e_k^T 
}$$
where $e_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ orthonormal basis vector, i.e.
$\;e_k^Te_l=\d_{kl}$
With this, we can calculate the component-wise gradient of the matrix product
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\LR{MM^T}}{M_{kl}} &= e_ke_l^TM^T+Me_le_k^T \\
}$$
Extracting the $(i,j)$ component of this expression recovers the components
of the fourth-order gradient tensor $\lR{\G\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n\times n\times n}}$
$$\eqalign{
\G_{ijkl} &= \grad{\LR{MM^T}_{ij}}{M_{kl}} \\
 &= e_i^T\LR{e_ke_l^T M^T}e_j \;+\; e_i^T\LR{M e_le_k^T}e_j \\
 &= \d_{ik} M_{lj}^T \;+\; M_{il} \d_{kj} \\
 &= \d_{ik} M_{jl} \;+\; M_{il} \d_{jk} \\
}$$

Thanks so much!
